# Error opening directory in Zotero: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, files, zotero

I am stuck with a (probably) silly problem:
[modifying preferences in Zotero-standalone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ie2E.jpg)!
I would like Zotero standalone in Ubuntu to point to the Zotero data in the Windows partition. [directory permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v5CG.jpg)
The 'Windows data partition' is mounted on a folder of mine.
So far Zotero replies that permission to access the directory is denied.

What can I test or correct?

```
rs@rs-XPS-12-9250:~$ lsblk -o name,partlabel,fstype,mountpoint,UUID
NAME   PARTLABEL                    FSTYPE   MOUNTPOINT                     UUID
loop0                               squashfs /snap/core/8268                
loop1                               squashfs /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110      
loop2                               squashfs /snap/chromium/971             
loop3                               squashfs /snap/gnome-calculator/406     
loop4                               squashfs /snap/gnome-characters/296     
loop5                               squashfs /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353   
loop6                               squashfs /snap/gnome-logs/61            
loop7                               squashfs /snap/gnome-characters/375     
loop8                               squashfs /snap/gnome-calculator/544     
loop9                               squashfs /snap/canonical-livepatch/90   
loop10                              squashfs /snap/core18/1288              
loop11                              squashfs /snap/gnome-logs/81            
loop12                              squashfs /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100 
loop13                              squashfs /snap/libreoffice/163          
loop14                              squashfs /snap/core/7270                
loop15                              squashfs /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67       
loop16                              squashfs /snap/zotero-snap/4            
loop17                              squashfs /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313   
loop18                              squashfs /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123 
loop19                              squashfs /snap/core18/1066              
sda                                                                         
├─sda1 Basic data partition         ntfs                                    0A9A78FF9A78E899
├─sda2 EFI system partition         vfat     /boot/efi                      9C79-CF74
├─sda3 Microsoft reserved partition                                         
├─sda4 Basic data partition         ntfs     /media/MSW10                   A44E81644E812FDA
├─sda5                              ntfs                                    963A9C573A9C3669
└─sda6                              ext4     /                              2bd5e8dc-7bce-460d-9a54-384a443d97d8
```

Comment: Need to see your partitions. Run `lsblk -o name,partlabel,fstype,mountpoint,UUID` and post output into question.

Comment: You need to label your partitions properly. You should move all your data files including Zotero to a **different partition** from Windows under folders describing such data. Which sda partition is your Windows (C: drive) system? What are the other sda partitions (1, 4 or 5) used for? I see sda4 is mounted. What files  are contained within?

Comment: Many thanks for taking care but, excuse me, I do not understand very well all your points.
Answering your questions requires more space than the 600 chars available, I will try to explain below what I am missing while I anticipate here what I might have understood.
In order to have a single local Zotero DB accessed both by MSWin and Ubuntu, I have to modify the Windows partitions, create a new one, and move there the Zotero data folder?

Comment: Your questions 
1. “You need to label your partitions properly.” 
All partition labels are generated by the software. Do you suggest that I label also sda5 and sda6? I suppose these are standard system partitions. Using the Disk utility I see following info
sda1 “Ambiente ripristino Microsoft Windows (Sistema)” Not mount
sda2 “Sistema EFI”  /boot/efi
sda3 “Microsoft riservata”  Contents: “Sconosciuto” [unknown]
sda4 “Basic Data”  /media/MSW10
sda5 “Ambiente ripristino Microsoft Windows (Sistema)”  Not mount
sda6 “File system Linux”                                                    /

Comment: Your questions   
2. "You should move all your data files including Zotero to a different partition from Windows under folders describing such data"  
You suggest to create a new partition (with Windows?), label it "Windows Data" and move there the sqlite data folder?

Comment: Your questions   
3. “Which sda partition is your Windows (C: drive) system?”
I mounted sda4 on /media/MSW10 because I see there the folders I see listing in C:
Does this answer your question?  
Your questions   
4. “What are the other sda partitions (1, 4 or 5) used for? I see sda4 is mounted. What files are contained within?”
sda1 and sda5  seem to be  Microsoft system restoration partitions
sda4 is mounted as /media/MSW10 because I see the folders I see on C: (including Zotero data folders)

Answer (score 1):

To access data stored on a mounted NTFS partition on Ubuntu in Zotero:

1. Open Ubuntu Software app and find zotero-snap
2. Click on Permissions
3. Toggle "Read/write files on removable storage devices" to on
4. Close and reopen Zotero

Note: The partition is mounted with these permissions/options: `ntfs auto,user,rw 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

OK. You've answered my questions. The point about labeling partitions is that you can see at a glance what partition contains what information. In your example you have 2 NTFS drives both labelled with the same description - *Basic data partition*, which is confusing. What I suggest is that you label sda4, Win10. Then you know it's your C:\ drive. If sda1 is a recovery drive, label that as WinRec or similar. If you look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En24A.jpg) you can see I've used proper labels for each partition, not the default ones, so I can see quickly what they all represent.

You can also see that my *sda4* is my data partition where all data files and folders are shared between Ubuntu and Windows. I keep all data separately from the system partitions, so that a) If I ever need to reinstall Windows the data isn't affected. b) I now can reference the data partition directly from Ubuntu without the need to load my Windows system as well. c) I now mount *sda4* at boot-up so that no permission problems arise as I can now make my own permissions in the */etc/fstab* file.

To return to your original question I would suggest you do similar, ie make a new partition, format it NTFS, label it 'Data' and move all data folders and files (not just Zotero) from your C:\ drive to the new partition. Once you've done that I'll tell you how to proceed from there.

Comment: I now understand  very well your suggestion, many thanks. Till now I have avoided making an extra partition and moving the Windows area data there, this would complicate the management of other aspects.   
Since, from Ubuntu I can open the Zotero data folder and see my _rw_ permissions also on the sqlite file I do not understand what happens when Zotero standalone tries to access.   

`> rs@rs-XPS-12-9250:/media/MSW10/Users/ro/Zotero$ ls -la`
`> -rw-rw---- 2 rs root 28860416 gen  6 16:58  zotero.sqlite`
Do you think that a new partition is necessary? Many thanks

Comment: I have a separate ntfs storage partition mounted, but Zotero still cannot access the directory. It appears to be a problem with Zotero reading and writing to ntfs, not whether the partition contains the Windows system files.

Comment: @koyakun When the storage partition is mounted, who is the owner of the mounted folder and what are the permissions for that folder and its mounted subfolders/files?